# Custom Form Validation in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I'd like to validate multiple related properties in the Blazor form.

In my case; I'd like to make sure that the number of lines in two `InputArea`s are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor this scenario is handled by the `business logic validation`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#business-logic-validation

## other alternatives

It is also possible to use data annotations for multiple fields:

> Performs validation based on multiple properties of the class
>
> - Create a custom data validation attribute to decorate a single    property.
> - Create a custom data validation attribute to decorate the    model class.
>
> http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/55bef03e-3d41-4a0a-b874-78b7c7a9ce36.aspx

Another approach is to use `OnSubmit` to use custom code to trigger validation and check field values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editform.onsubmit?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_Forms_EditForm_OnSubmit

Another option is to create a `model` from your `form`; and then use `model validation`:

- `AttributeAdapter for client-side validation`
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attributeadapter-for-client-side-validation

  `IClientModelValidator for client-side validation`
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iclientmodelvalidator-for-client-side-validation

It is also possible to use FluentValidation with Blazor: https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/

p.s. I don't know this area well; so am probably missing something